# Problem with highlighting code in markdown files with shikiji - Nuxt.js

Tags: nuxt.js, markdown, nuxt-content

I'm creating a blog website using Nuxt.js and Nuxt content module that use markdown files and higlight code block with "shikiji", but when I'm building project I see warning in console:

`WARN  (inject plugin) rollup-plugin-inject: failed to parse D:/(PATH)/(PROJECT_NAME)/node_modules/shikiji/dist/onig.wasm. Consider restricting the plugin to particular files via options.include".`

This is code that I copied from Nuxt content docs to my nuxt.config.js file:

```js
content: {
    highlight: {
      theme: 'github-light'
    }
},
```

I tried to find some resolutions in google, github copilot, try to find file "options.include", search about this file etc. but I don't have a lot of experience in solving this type of problems and language barrier.

I'm expecting to highlight code in code blocks as in this block I paste above with `nuxt.config.js` file content.